# Verify a method was never called with OCMock 3

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ocmock

How do I verify a method is never called with [OCMock 3](http://ocmock.org/reference/)?

I was thinking something like this:

```
XCTAssertThrows(OCMVerify([_restDataSource getSomeStuff:[OCMArg any]]));
```

But it seems like OCMVerify doesn't throw for a fail.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please see first point under http://ocmock.org/reference/#advanced-topics

Note that `reject` at this point in time requires the old-style syntax and it must be called before the method may be invoked, ie.

```
// first set up the mock
[[mock reject] methodThatShouldNotBeCalled]
// then call method that should not result in the call
```

For a glimpse on what's planned, see https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/issues/109

Comment: Thanks for a nice tool Erik.

Answer (score 1):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36888947/1820856), starting from version 3.3 OCMock has [OCMReject](http://ocmock.org/reference/#advanced-topics) macro.

Answer (score 0):

I failed miserably at getting the *reject-method* to work so my solution was to simply stub the *method-not-to-be-called*(notifyChange: in example below) with throwing an exception whenever it is called.

```
// Set up the mock.
id<TSModelObserver> observer = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(TSModelObserver));

// Stub the forbidden method call with throwing an exception.    
[OCMStub([observer notifyChange:model]) andThrow:[NSException new]];
```